# How to minimize two variables in a set of equations?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, optimization, diophantine-equations, integer-programming

I was working on a problem which I reduced to as follows:

- $a + 2b + 3c + 4d = 665$
- $a + b + c + d = 200$

I want to find the value of $(c+d)$ which is minimum which also satisfies the given 2 constraints.

I tried to substitute values in $1^{st}$ equation by substituting, $c=200$ but then that wont work we need to have some non-zero value of $c$ and $ d$. But I am confused as to how to arrive at the right value? Do i have to check all the values by brute-force or is there a smarter way to get about it?

Comment: From where do you want to know that there is a Minimum?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I didnt quite get you. The original question was something like there are 200 people, everyone has either 1 ball or 2 or 3 or 4 balls. Find the minimum number of people with atleast 3 balls. I tried to shape the question into this way and solve it. Can u point me in the right direction from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying the first constraint by $0.5$, the second constraint by $-1$, and each of the lower bounds $a\ge 0$ and $c \ge 0$ by $0.5$ yields $c+d\ge 132.5$, hence integrality implies that 133 is a lower bound on the optimal objective value. Now $(1,66,0,133)$ satisfies the constraints and achieves that bound and is therefore optimal.  The magic dual multipliers come from linear programming.

Comment: Nice solution! I had solved this question yesterday by noting that for every decrease in $b$ by 1, I can increase the total sum of constraint $1$ by $2$ if I increase $d$ by 1 so I reached the solution of (0,68,1,132). Is there a particular way to use these dual multipliers or did u use $0.5$ and $-1$ by trial and error?

Comment: Hmm, your $(0,68,1,132)$ solution does not satisfy the constraints. The dual multipliers are a byproduct of solving the LP relaxation, with optimal solution $(0,67.5,0,132.5)$.

Comment: Oops, my bad! I had meant to write $(0,67,1,132)$. Cool so I'll loop up LP relaxation.